# ngx-bootstrap carousel - how to modify indicators,Prev and Next Button

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, angular6, ngx-bootstrap

```
<carousel >
  <a href="">
  <slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
     <img src="{{slide.imgUrl}}" alt="" style="display: 
           block; width: 100%;">
  </slide>
```

1.How to replace the indicators with the images icon?
2.How to show indicators in rounded instead of line?

Comment: All these things are achieved with CSS. What have you tried to change in CSS so far?

Answer (score 0):

Your document inspector can quickly show you where changes need to be made. Right-click, inspect.

```
.carousel-indicators li::before {
    background-image: url(...);
    /* OR */
    content: 'somechar';
    font-family: someFontFamily;
}
```

Comment: This code is not working..it's not override internal caurosel.scss

Comment: You didn't tag SCSS and I didn't write SCSS. I tested it on the official demo and it works. You'll need to provide a custom demo if you'd like more specific help.